# #awk If else loop not working in ksh

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, clearcase

I have code where awk is piped to a clearcase command where If else loop is not working.

code is below :

```
#!/bin/ksh    
export dst_region=$1    
cleartool lsview -l | gawk -F":" \ '{ if ($0 ~ /Global path:/) { if($dst_region == "ABC" || $dst_region -eq "ABC") { system("echo dest_region is ABC");} 
else { system("echo dest_region is not ABC"); } }; }'
```

But when I execute the above script the I get incorrect output,

```
*$ ksh script.sh ABCD

dest_region is ABC

$ ksh script.sh ABC 

dest_region is ABC*
```

Could anyone please help on this issue ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample output from `cleartool lsview -l` and explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: You appear to have confused `awk` syntax and shell syntax in that awk script. `awk` variables don't require `$` when being used (except the positional ones and in indirect evaluation conditions). `-eq` is a shell conditional test (for `test`/`[`) not an `awk` conditional. `$dst_region` is a shell variable in your snippet but is being used in the awk script (and isn't working there because you wrapped the awk script in single quotes which prevent shell variable expansion).

Comment: Yes, I was confused with the variables between The shell variable and awk variables. As you said single quotes were blocking the shell variable expansion, I was need to create awk variable for proper variable value assignment, thank you VonC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful if you explained exactly what you are trying to do but your awk script can be cleaned up a lot:

```
 gawk -F":" -vdst_region="$1" '/Global path:/ { if (dst_region == "ABC") print "dest_region is ABC"; else print "dest_region is not ABC" }'
```

General points:

- I have used `-v` to create an awk variable from the value of `$1`, the first argument to the script. This means that you can use it a lot more easily in the script.
- awk's structure is `condition { action }` so you're using `if` around the whole one-liner unnecessarily
- `$0 ~ /Global path:/` can be changed to simply `/Global path:/`
- the two sides of the `||` looked like they were trying to both do the same thing, so I got rid of the one that doesn't work in awk. Strings are compared using `==`.
- `system("echo ...")` is completely unnecessary. Use awk's built in `print`

You could go one step further and remove the `if-else` entirely:

```
 gawk -F":" -vdst_region="$1" '/Global path:/ { printf "dest region is%s ABC", (dst_region=="ABC"?"":" not") }'
```

Comment: Worked like charm !!! The issue is resolved with the creating variable in awk command itself with "-v" and assigning the command line argument to it. thank you Tom.